# How to create a list of spatial objects and merge them in R

Tags: raster, r, merge, loop

I’m trying to load and merge a bunch of .tif spatial files from ASTER. Sorry, I can’t provide a replicable example, but I hope this ilustrates the situation:

```
library(raster)  
pathz <- "C:/USERS/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR/" 
# The subdirectory where my .tif files are  
filez <- list.files(path = paste(pathz, "/Granules", sep = ""), pattern = ".tif")  
# I get the list of files
namez <- paste("r", c(1:length(filez)), sep = "") 
# I create the bunch of spatial objects 
for(i in 1:length(filez)){  
   temp <- raster(paste(pathz, "/Granules/", filez[i], sep = ""))  
   assign(namez[i], temp)  
}  
# This way, I've created 200 RasterLayer objects, for example  
r49  
class       : RasterLayer  
dimensions  : 3601, 3601, 12967201  (nrow, ncol, ncell)  
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)  
extent      : -76.00014, -74.99986, 1.999861, 3.000139  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)  
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0  
data source : C:\Users\Paolo\Desktop\Aster DEM\Granules\ASTGTM2_N02W076_dem.tif   
names       : ASTGTM2_N02W076_dem  
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)  
class(namez)  
[1] "character"  
namez1 <- as.list(namez)  
class(namez1)    
[1] "list"  
namez1  
[[1]]
[1] "r1"

[[2]]
[1] "r2"

[[3]]
[1] "r3"  
# etc

# Obviously it did not work  
m <- do.call(merge, namez1)  
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column  
# I tried...  
namez1 <- as.environment(namez1)  
Error in list2env(list("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8",  :  
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x  
# Also...  
list2env(namez1, envir = NULL)  
Error in list2env(namez1, envir = NULL) :  
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x  
# Of course...
is.vector(namez1)  
[1] TRUE
```

Specifically, I wish to know how to create a list of spatial objects so I can merge them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are they multiple layers of a single (3D) raster?

`brick(filez)`

Are they disparate windows from a single layer parent (2D) raster?

`Reduce(merge, lapply(filez, raster))`

Are they disparate 2D rasters with no common grid? (sounds like it, given "Granule")

`Reduce(mosaic, lapply(filez, raster))`

I suggest testing each of those options on small subsets of `filez`. Treat all R work like that, get the set of all filenames, test a single thing, like `myrasters <- lapply(filez, raster)`, explore a few with a plot `plot(myrasters[[1]])` `plot(myrasters[[10]])` then try the next thing like `merge` (on a small example, two of those rasters).

My use of `Reduce` adds another level of abstraction here, but consider that

`merge(myrasters[[1]], myrasters[[10]])`

allows us to merge just two rasters at a time, `Reduce` avoids us needing to call `merge` on every pair in sequence and accumulate as we go, so it's pretty abstract but **super powerful**.

Don't use `assign`, it just creates lots of named things lying around you have to futz with.

Comment: is there a stars way to merge "disparate windows from a single layer parent (2D) raster"?

Comment: I don't know -  I haven't explored stars for this, or anything with these cell-abstractions that raster has yet, I don't think c.stars or merge.stars does this

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is because your list contains only the names of the rasters and not the rasters themselves. First `get` the rasters and then you can apply `do.call`:

```
namez1.get <- lapply(namez1, get)
m <- do.call(merge, namez1.get)
```

But, the best way would be to directly create this list of rasters in your loop:

```
r.list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(filez)){  
   r.list[[i]] <- raster(paste(pathz, "/Granules/", filez[i], sep = ""))  
} 
m <- do.call(merge, r.list)
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can thank by upvoting and validating the answer. Thanks.